# How to disbale 1D scanner code on mobile device in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, barcode-scanner, scanning

I am using 1D scanner i.e "https://www.issyzonepos.com/ipda018-android-7-0-pda-bluetooth-4-1-support-gprs-wifi_p326.html"  for my app. The app is basically to scan code and order data. I have also implemented a scanner through a camera. My APP is working perfectly on this device but when I try to run it on a mobile device then it crashes on "sm = new ScanDevice();" as it is a non-scanner device. I tried a lot to resolve this can you tell me how can I solve this. I have used this device's SDK for the scanner.

Code:

```
    sm = new ScanDevice();

     public void onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    int charCode = event.getKeyCode();

    System.out.println("charCode = " + keyCode + "  " + event);
    //sm.openScan();

    if (charCode == 302 || charCode == 301 || charCode == 303) {
        if (spBar.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("SELECT BAR")) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.select_a_bar), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(actSearchCode.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

            System.out.println("openScannerL = " + sm.getOutScanMode());

            sm.openScan();
        }
    } else if (charCode == 82) {

    } else {
        sm.closeScan();
    }

}
```

For the sake of completeness, here's the stack trace of the error from the OP - unfortunately, as a screenshot.

[image]

Line 76 is `sm = new ScanDevice();`

Comment: The simplest thing is to just put `try`-`catch` around that line - and deal with it as appropriate. You need to show a bit more of your code if you want any more specific help

Comment: @AleksG check my updated code

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can just create your scanner instance inside a `try-catch` block.  For this, you'll have to declare the variable in a class, but instantiate it in a method. Your code still doesn't show where you're declaring your `sm`, but you may end up with something like this:

```
public class MyScanActivity extends Activity {
    ScanDevice sm;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        try {
            ...
            sm = new ScannerDevice();
            ...
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.w("SCANNER_ACTIVITY", "Could not create scanner device - not a scanner?");
        }
        ...
    }

    public void onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        ...
        if (sm == null) {
            Log.i("SCANNER_ACTIVITY", "Scanner not instantiated - not a scanner?");
        } else {
            // all your scanning code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not working. crashing and throwing error . http://prntscr.com/oh98fk

Comment: @mishti What is line 76?

Comment: sm = new ScannerDevice();

Comment: @mishti try changing `catch (Exception ex)` to `catch (Throwable ex)`